# How can ActiveX control elements in a word document be parsed?

Tags: ms-word, activex

I understand this perhaps is not the ideal question as per the guidelines that require you to be specific, but I'm looking for a way to be able to parse out word documents such as fillable forms that make use of ActiveX control elements. Are there any libraries or tool available that can be used for this purpose?

Thanks!